# How to use html in radio button choices r shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to update a radiobutton list on the server side with HTML code but I'm not succeeding.
I'm using this example for you to understand what I'm trying to do. I refer again that has to be on the server side because the elements on my list will be related to other inputs made by the user.

Can someone help to figure out how it can be made?
thanks

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
radioButtons("rb", "Choose one:",
             choiceNames = list("icon", "html", "text"),
             choiceValues = c(1,2,3)),
 textOutput("txt")
) 


server <- function(input, output,session) {


a<-HTML("<p style='color:red;'>option2</p>")
list1=as.list(c("option1",a,"option3"))

  updateRadioButtons(session, "rb", choiceNames = list1, choiceValues = c(1,2,3))



output$txt <- renderText({
  paste("You chose", input$rb)
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

`choiceValues` must be an atomic vector, not a list

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("rb", "Choose one:",
               choiceNames = list("icon", "html", "text"),
               choiceValues = c(1,2,3)),
  textOutput("txt")
)
```

if you use `updateXXX` you have to set the argument `session` to the `server` function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
```

in `updateRadioButtons` you have to set both `choiceNames` and `choiceValues`:

```
  if(TRUE){  
    list=list(icon("calendar"),
              HTML("<p style='color:red;'>Red Text</p>"),
              "Normal text"
    )
    updateRadioButtons(session, "rb", choiceNames = list, choiceValues = c(1,2,3))
  }
```

And the `icon` does not work.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the example for you to better understand the problem. When I concatenate the HTML content in a vector, it doesnt work.

Comment: @HugoSilva Yes, you can't do that. Do `list("option1", a, "option3")`.